# PHP float to string

Tags: php

I must convert float and int to string in array..

```
for($x = 0; $x < $ile; $x++)
        {
        $myArray['result']['items'][$x]['id'];
        echo '<pre>';
        $myArray['result']['items'][$x]['id'];  
        $tablica[$x] = $myArray['result']['items'][$x]['id'];
        echo '</pre>';
        var_dump ($tablica[$x]);
        echo '<br/>';
        }
```

Return:

```
int(81121789) 
int(207360665) 
int(683847370) 
int(1256003572) 
float(2535676003) 
float(5158703351) 
float(5266812473) 
float(5267345149) 
float(5267945040)
```

How i can convert this numbers, to string? btw. $myArray is json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) this will call the native `__toString()` method on the class/instance that is passed to it. You could also accomplish your desired layout like this.

```
echo '<pre>';
$items = $myArray['result']['items'];
$tablica = [];
foreach($items as $item)
    $tablica[] = strval($item['id']);
}
var_dump($tablica);
echo '</pre>';
```

Alternatively you could force the type to a string like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
$items = $myArray['result']['items'];
$tablica = [];
foreach($items as $item)
    $tablica[] = (string) $item['id'];
}
var_dump($tablica);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find a problem
$tablica[$x] = (string) $myArray['result']['items'][$x]['id'];